# Modal view controller works on iOS 7, leaves a gap on iOS 6

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios7, uistatusbar

So I have this custom UIViewController subclass, that I present modally with `-presentViewController:animated:` (NOT pushing it onto a navigation stack).  I'm trying to make it play nicely with both iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Said VC is built in a .xib file (no storyboard is involved).  I have a custom navigation bar in there, along with some other UI elements.  When I run it in iOS 7, I get this:

[image]

It looks correct; my custom nag bar correctly abuts the status bar.

However, when I run the same thing in iOS 6, I get:

[image]

Notice the black gap (that's the background of the view) between the status bar and my custom nav bar. :(

In the .xib file, I have the view's contents shifted down from the top of the view by 20 pixels; *AND* I have the view's "iOS 6/7 Deltas" for deltaY set to "-20".  It obviously ain't working.

What am I missing here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of a view's "iOS 6/7 Deltas" depends on the '*View as*` settings as specified in the '*Interface Builder Document*' inspector (select '*View*' -> '*Utilities*' -> '*Show Utilities*', then click on the left-most icon on top of the utilities-pane and look at the responsible '*Interface Builder Document*' section's '*View as*' PopUpList).

Tweak your "iOS 6/7 Deltas" to adjust for the iOS version that is currently **not** showing (e.g. if you have set '*View as*' to '*iOS7 and later*', tweak the deltas for '*iOS 6.1 and Earlier*').

Hence, your deltaY settings of **"-20"** are correct only, if you have set '*View as*' to '*iOS 7.0 and Later*'. Once your setting are correct, you can play with the '*View as*' PopUpList and your VC will always look correct right away.

Hope, this helps.